# Convert date format from '1996-97' to 1996-1997'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of NBA players from years 1996 to 2012. The season column is in this format "1996-97" but I would like to convert it from that to '1996 - 1997'. I noticed that if I go further down to year 2000, it appears as "1999-00'. This does not look good.
I tried using the following code`

```
all_seasons['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_seasons['Date'], format='%Y-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%Y')
```

It returned an error: redefinition of group name 'Y' as group 2; was group 1.

I also used this code

```
all_seasons['Date'] = all_seasons['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%Y')
```

but it returned the error

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried `all_seasons['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_seasons['Date'], format='%Y-%y').dt.strftime('%Y-%Y')`?

Comment: I did, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to datetimes last 2 numbers and then add to first 4 numbers:

```
print (df)
      Date
0  1996-97
1  1999-00

df['Date'] = (df.Date.str[:4] + 
                     pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str[-2:], format='%y').dt.strftime(' - %Y'))
print (df)
          Date
0  1996 - 1997
1  1999 - 2000
```

Or if use `%Y-%y` format it parse second year, so added to first 4 digits:

```
df['Date'] = df.Date.str[:4] + pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%y').dt.strftime(' - %Y')
print (df)
          Date
0  1996 - 1997
1  1999 - 2000
```

Comment: I am yet to try this. I will do so and get back to you. Thank you so much Jezrael!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and a custom function.

For example, here we replace `xx` with `19xx` if `xx` is ≥ 60, else `20xx`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1996-97', '1999-00']})

df['Date2'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r'(\d\d)$',
              lambda m: ('19' if int(m.group())>=60 else '20')+m.group(),
              regex=True)
```

output (as separate column Date2 for clarity):

```
      Date      Date2
0  1996-97  1996-1997
1  1999-00  1999-2000
```

Comment: Thanks, Mozway, it worked but I don't understand the argument in the str. replace() .  I was able to modify it so it doesn't print a separate date column but replaces the existing one. I will have to read up regex functions and lambda in data frames. I am still a newbie so it's a lot for me to understand.

Comment: @piya to replace the column use `df['Date'] = ...` instead of `df['Date2'] = ...`. The regex extracts the last two digits and prepends them with 19 of those two digits form a number ≥ 60, else by 19.